# Tracking 1st arrival of two brothers to US in early 20th century?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, immigration

Gregor and Lluk Lakuriqi arrived in the U.S. in 1911.
They stayed until 1919, left and came back in 1920.

Here is a timeline for them:

- Gregor born 1894 in Albania (then Turkey), Greek Orthodox
- Lluk born 1902 in Albania (then Turkey), Greek Orthodox
- Gregor was in the US in 1917 (WWI draft registration card)
- They arrived in the port of New York on the ship Madonna (passenger list for the Madonna arriving 22 Mar 1920)
- Lluk submitted a Petition for Naturalization in 1925
- That around 1917 they lived in Philadelphia.

Also, here are the know variants of their names:

- Lakuriqi / Lakurigi
- Lluk, Luka, Lucas
- Gregor, Grigor, Gori, Grigorios

I haven't been able to locate them in the Ellis Island / NY / Philadelphia / Boston arrivals.

**Could anyone give me a hint, I'm getting clueless on where to locate their 1911 arrival.**

Link to documents : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3oo6dikacexn5lg/AABdzGKhMHZuBG3aBBBgY-h3a?dl=0

Some more (incomplete) information:

- Lluk left and came back in 1933, at that time he lived in NJ (Vineland) (source Ellis records)
- Gregor died (in Philadelphia?) between 1920 and 1927(?) (haven't been able to find death record

---

Source list:

- arrival date 22 Mar 1920 for ship Madonna departing  Naples, Italy (lines 21, 22) [page 1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3oo6dikacexn5lg/AABdzGKhMHZuBG3aBBBgY-h3a?dl=0&preview=Lakurigi_Gregorio_Lucas_Ellis_PassengerLists_1920_p1.jpg) page 2 *Passenger and Crew Lists of Vessels Arriving at New York, New York, 1897-1957. Microfilm Publication T715, Roll 2742; Page Number 124)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59076/discussion-on-question-by-j-j-d-tracking-1st-arrival-of-two-brothers-to-us-in-e).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some of the information from the comments (such as the 'when in the US before' dates from the 1920 passenger list) to the question, using the edit link underneath.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for hints.  This is what I've come up with.

There is a public member tree managed by *kristinka*  on Ancestry.com that contains a woman's name - Amali LAKURIQI, whose maiden name is ZOTO.  She was born in 1910 and died in 2002  The name of her husband is apparently unknown.  In trying to explore further, I used [newspapers.com](http://newspapers.com) and found, among numerous other ZOTOs, Anesti ZOTO who died 21 Jul 1993.  He had been born about 1911, come to America, left again in 1936 to go home and get married, and lived a happy productive life in Philadelphia.  He was a founding member of

- **St. John Chrysostom Albania Orthodox Church** at 17th and Vine in Philadelphia

This led me to think that it could be very helpful for you to try to identify similar churches where Lluk may have worshipped.  This may lead to date of death for Gregorios.  Churches that existed then may have been folded into different churches that exist today and still have access to records.  Or it may actually still exist.

I don't know if you have a wife's name for Lluk, but if not, you may wish to look into Amali LAKURIQI's close family members.

Since Lluk was 8 or 9 when he first traveled to America, and Gregorios not much more than a boy himself, try searching using their father's name, Antonio, according to papers you've collected.  Or some of the names Lluk ultimately gave his children as they may have been important adults in his first family and may have accompanied him to America that first time.

Comment: Thanks for information! Unfortunately, nothing new on the horizon: (i) Amali Lakuriqi (Nee Zoto) was Luka's wife. She came later to the U.S. with her children, when Luka had already passed away. (ii) The father of Luka and Gregorios stayed in Albania and remarried, Luka and Gregorios came when their mother passed away. (iii) Anesti Zoto is unrelated. (iv) St John Chrysostom church started 'officially' after the death of Gregorios. Thanks for your help though.